# Java - Set Period

Tags: java, period

I want to make an analysis of some time barriers and I'm having some doubts about the best approach to define 'Period'.

I'm working with time passed from the start, I mean:

```
Start - "00:00:00"
Checkpoint 1 - "2:10:02"
End - "03:00:00"
```

So, what kind of object should I use to translate the string? Later I'll want to make some averages, etc.

Comment: is you code java8-able?

Comment: [Period::between](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#between-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalDate-)

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`Duration.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) (requires Java 8 or later).

Comment: [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). It prints differently, but search for questions about parsing and formatting the format with colons that you use, they are out there.

Comment: I take it that the times are relative to the start time? Not times of day, are they?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) for example, you could use this and manipulate it however necessary:

```
String start = "02:10:02";
String end = "03:00:00";

LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(start);
LocalTime lt2 = LocalTime.parse(end);
Duration dur = Duration.between(lt, lt2);
System.out.println("Diff is: " + dur.getSeconds());
```

**Output:**

> Diff is: 2998

Then do whatever you need with the seconds.

Comment: If the times are not time of day, `LocalTime` is incorrect. `Duration` is good under all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) and [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) although you will need a custom format to parse time with single hour digit.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss");

LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("00:00:00", fmt);
LocalTime checkpoint = LocalTime.parse("2:10:02", fmt);
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse("03:00:00", fmt);

System.out.println(Duration.between(start, checkpoint)); // PT2H10M2S
System.out.println(Duration.between(checkpoint, end)); // PT49M58S
System.out.println(Duration.between(start, end)); // PT3H
```

Comment: If the times are not time of day, `LocalTime` is incorrect.